# Sampling from conditional distiribution

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

I want to sample from condtional distribution given by formula:
$$ P[T_{n+1} =t| T_n=t_n] = \frac{\alpha_t+m_(t_n)}{\alpha_t+\beta_t+s(t_n)}\prod^{t-1}_{j=0}\frac{\beta_j+r_j(t_n)}{\alpha_j+\beta_j+s_j(t_n)}$$
$t_n$ is a vector of given data,$s,r$-sums depending on vector $t_n$

Comment: What are your difficulties regarding this?

Comment: What algorithm should I use?